# Inserting DIV element before HTML comment

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to insert div with iframe before HTML comment (it is the only unique element at this position).

So I have comment like: `<!--  Comment -->` and I would like to insert code like this before the comment:

```
<div id="test">
    <noscript>
      <iframe src="https://test.net" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="742" height="92"></iframe>
    </noscript>
</div>
```

I tried methods like .append() and prepend(), but without success.

The result should be:

```
    <div id="test">
        <noscript>
          <iframe src="https://test.net" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="742" height="92"></iframe>
        </noscript>
    </div>
<!--  Comment -->
```

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: @Duane ofcourse you can select a comment!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.filter()` return element where `nodeType` is `8`

```js
var div = "<div>abc</div>";

var comment = $("body").contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType === 8
});

$(div).insertBefore(comment);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<!--  Comment --> 
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML comment has is a Node in DOM hierarchy and it's nodeType property is 8.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var _html = '<div id="test">' 
    + '<noscript>' 
    + '<iframe src="https://test.net" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="742" height="92"></iframe>' 
    + '</noscript>' 
    + '</div>';

    $('body').contents().each(function (i, elem) {
        if (elem.nodeType == 8 && elem.data == "  Comment ") {
            $(_html).insertBefore(elem);
        }
    });

});
```

So traverse through all the comments find the one which you want and insert the HTML before that comment node.

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/109uw639/)